# What does recurrent_initializer do?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

I am experimenting with recurrent neural network layers in tensorflow & keras and I am having a look at the recurrent_initializer. I wanted to know more about its influence on the layer, so I created a SimpleRnn layer as the follows:

```
rnn_layer = keras.layers.SimpleRNN(1, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.ones, recurrent_initializer=keras.initializers.zeros, activation="linear")
```

Running this code, makes the addition in the recurrent net visible:

```
inp = np.zeros(shape=(1,1,20), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(20):
    inp[0][0][:i] = 5
    #inp[0][0][i:] = 0
    
    print(f"i:{i} {rnn_layer(inp)}"'')
```

output:

```
i:0 [[[0.]]]
i:1 [[[5.]]]
i:2 [[[10.]]]
i:3 [[[15.]]]
i:4 [[[20.]]]
i:5 [[[25.]]]
i:6 [[[30.]]]
i:7 [[[35.]]]
i:8 [[[40.]]]
i:9 [[[45.]]]
i:10 [[[50.]]]
i:11 [[[55.]]]
i:12 [[[60.]]]
i:13 [[[65.]]]
i:14 [[[70.]]]
i:15 [[[75.]]]
i:16 [[[80.]]]
i:17 [[[85.]]]
i:18 [[[90.]]]
i:19 [[[95.]]]
```

Now I change the recurrent_initializer to something different, like a glorot_normal distribution:

```
rnn_layer = keras.layers.SimpleRNN(1, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer = keras.initializers.ones, recurrent_initializer=keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=0), activation="linear")
```

But I still get the same results. I thought it might depend on some logic, which a Rnn is missing but a LSTM has, so I tried it with an lstm, but still same results. I guess there is something about the recurrent_logic, I still miss. Can someone explain me, what the reccurent_initializers purpose is and how it affects the recurrent layer?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input to the RNN layer is of shape (1, 1, 20), which mean one Timestep for each batch , the default behavior of RNN is to RESET state between each batch , so you cant see the effect of the recurrent ops(the recurrent_initializers).
You have to change the length of the sequence of your input:

```
inp = np.ones(shape=(5 ,4,1), dtype=np.float32) # sequence length == 4
rnn_layer1 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1,return_state=True, return_sequences=False, 
           kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.ones, 
           recurrent_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.zeros, activation="linear")
rnn_layer2 = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(1,return_state=True , return_sequences=False, 
           kernel_initializer = tf.keras.initializers.ones, 
           recurrent_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.glorot_normal(seed=0), 
           activation="linear")

first_sample = inp[0 : 1 , : ,:  ] #shape(1,4,1)
print(rnn_layer1(first_sample )
print(rnn_layer2(first_sample )
```

Comment: Just found that solution by myself, still many thanks for your explanation! I will now experiment some more with it to understand it better, your answer will help me well